# Parse soundcloud "/sets/" url with Regular Expressions in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to do a regular expression to parse an soundcloud to an embed code extracted from a link

so Far if I put this url: https://soundcloud.com/theredrojomusic/animal that is converted to a link first and then changed to the embed code fine with this(that took form a vimeo/youtube/metacafe regex):

```
array(
   'https{0,1}:\/\/w{0,3}\.*soundcloud\.com\/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)\/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)[^< ]*',
   '<iframe width="100%" height="'.$s.'" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http://soundcloud.com/$1/$2&amp;auto_play=false&hide_related=true&show_comments=false&show_user=true&show_reposts=false&visual=false"></iframe>')
```

The problem is when i Try to parse a set like: https://soundcloud.com/theredrojomusic/sets/tristezza

This just render the url as `https://soundcloud.com/theredrojomusic/sets` and the embed code can't handle.

I tried this:

```
array(
    'https{0,1}:\/\/w{0,3}\.*soundcloud\.com\/([A-Za-z0-9_-])\/sets\/*([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)[^< ]*',
    '<iframe width="100%" height="'.$s.'" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http://soundcloud.com/$1/sets/$2&amp;auto_play=false&hide_related=true&show_comments=false&show_user=true&show_reposts=false&visual=false"></iframe>'),
```

But the rendered url there is `https://soundcloud.com/c/sets/tristezza`

I would like to have two regex, one for non `/sets/` urls and other with `/sets/`, because the embed code is a little different (at least if I want the `/sets/` one to look like a list instead of just a song.)

I'm pretty bad with regex really... Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first regular expression is

```
https{0,1}:\/\/w{0,3}\.*soundcloud\.com\/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)\/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)[^< ]*
```

and after the `soundcloud\.com` there are two forward slashes followed by alpha-numeric sequences. Hence it can match `soundcloud.com/wordOne/wordTwo`. The set that is not matched (ie `https://soundcloud.com/theredrojomusic/sets/tristezza`) looks like `soundcloud.com/wordOne/wordTwo/wordThree`.

The two examples do not show what character follow the wanted text, however the final part of the first regular expression is `[^< ]*` which does not do anything useful. It says look for zero or more character that are not left-chevron or space, but it does nothing with them. Assuming that a left-chevron or a space marks the end of the wanted text then changing the regular expression  to be

```
https{0,1}:\/\/w{0,3}\.*soundcloud\.com\/([A-Za-z0-9_-\/]+)[< ]
```

or even

```
https{0,1}:\/\/w{0,3}\.*soundcloud\.com\/([^< ]+)[< ]
```

The first look for any sequence of alphanumerics plus forward-slash followed by a left-chevron or space. The second looks for a sequence of any characters except a left-chevron or space. Without a more precise statement of what is wanted it is difficult to say what regular expression is needed.

Later in the both sections of code there is a `src=...` clause. Within that there is a `$1/$2` and that would need to be changed to `$1`.

Update

To match on strings with and without `/sets/` I would suggest using the expressions given above which will find both versions. Then follow that with an `if` statement that checks whether the matched text contains `/sets/`.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't too clear. @AdrianHHH I took the regex idea from other modification that parse the content in a question site [link](http://av.pregunten.net/73/que-clase-de-efecto-tiene-la-voz-de-esta-cancion) to show vimeo/youtube/metacafe videos, this converts <a> into embed data. Your last regex catch both kinds of links (even groups) just needed to add a `*` in the end `https{0,1}:\/\/w{0,3}\.*soundcloud\.com\/([^< ]+)[< ]*` But I would like to do two different and regex, one that catches "/sets/" links and other that catches non "/sets/". I will update this in my question. Thanks

Comment: I used the last one (adding the *) for the general urls, and this. `https{0,1}:\/\/w{0,3}\.*soundcloud\.com\/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)\/sets\/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)[^< ]*` for the sets changing then to `https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http://soundcloud.com/$1/sets/$2&amp` Thanks